# Spring doesn't save object to MongoDB correctly

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

**Following question has been separated from this one:**
[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while Spring save data to MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264827/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-while-spring-save-data-to-mongodb)

I have problem with saving Object to MongoDB. I've noticed that problem might be caused by too complex object. I have following class hierarchy:
[image]

`ClassA` is superclass for `ClassB` and `ClassC`. `ClassD` contains map of maps. `ClassC` contains `ClassB`.

Code which I invoke is following:

```
ClassC c = new ClassC()
c.setName("NAME");
mongoOperation.save(c, "Mongo"); // MongoOperations object
```

The problem is that Mongo doesn't save object's data. It saves only `_id` and `_class`.

**Actual data**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e86cd9c506f66eafaa03cb"),
    "_class" : "com.sample.ClassC"
}
```

**Expected data**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e86cd9c506f66eafaa03cb"),
    "_class" : "com.sample.ClassC",
    "name" : "NAME"
}
```

Funny thing is that when I comment out map field in `ClassD` everything works fine.

**Is it possible to be caused by too complex object which I try to serialize?**

---

**EDIT**

When I remove `bObject` from `ClassC` it also works fine.

---

**EDIT 2**

All classes are simple beans with setters and getters.

e.g.

```
public class ClassD{

    private TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String,String>> map;

    public TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 3**

Full example below, it has same class hierarchy as picture above.

```
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        ClassC cObject = new ClassC();
        cObject.setName("Jon");
        try {
            mongoTemplate.save(cObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mongoTemplate.save(cObject);
    }
}


class ClassA{

    private String name;

    private ClassD dObject;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ClassD getdObject() {
        return dObject;
    }

    public void setdObject(ClassD dObject) {
        this.dObject = dObject;
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
}

class ClassC extends ClassA {
    private ClassB b;

    public ClassB getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(ClassB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class ClassD {

    private TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> map = new TreeMap<>();

    public TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
    public void setMap(TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of ClassD?

Comment: All classes are simple beans with setters and getters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the `MongoConverter` in specific version of your spring-data-mongodb.jar works incorrectly.
Spring must convert your `ClassC` instance into `DBObject` format, then call `DBCollection.save` to save data into database. You can check the content of `DBObject` parameter in method `"com.mongodb.DBCollection.save"` whether it contains correct data as you expect.

I copy your `ClassC` with complete structure and test, it's fine and cannot reproduce what you described above. I use spring-data-mongdb-1.2.3-RELEASE.jar. What's the version you adopt?

Comment: My version is 1.5.0. When I used 1.0.1 it worked fine, but now I cannot downgrade it to any version lesser than 1.5.0...

Comment: Yes, version 1.5.0 has the bug. If you can use HashMap instead TreeMap, it will help you, else you have to wait for fixing the bug by the author. It happens in **spring-data-commons-1.8.0-RELEASE.jar**. The code treats `TreeMap` as normal entity class, but not container class. Unfortunately, the field definition in TreeMap has something different to HashMap, such as **private transient EntrySet entrySet = null;** in TreeMap - it's one of reasons to emit that exception.

Answer (score 3):

The following code seems to work:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Customer customer = new Customer("myself");
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> map =  new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>>();
        TreeMap<String, String> innermap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        innermap.put("iam", "cool");
        map.put("innermap", innermap);
        TreeMap<String, String> innermap2 = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        innermap2.put("youare", "yellow");
        map.put("innermap2", innermap2);
        classB.setMap(map);
        customer.setClassB(classB);
        try {
            mongoTemplate.save(customer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mongoTemplate.save(customer);
        System.out.println(mongoTemplate.findAll(Customer.class));;
    }
}


public class ClassB {

    private TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> map = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>>();

    public TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}


@Document(collection ="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private ClassB classB;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ClassB getClassB() {
        return classB;
    }

    public void setClassB(ClassB classB) {
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", classB=" + classB
                + "]";
    }

}
```

But [the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264827/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-while-spring-save-data-to-mongodb) is still present.

Comment: Your code works fine, but it has completely different class hierarchy. I've attached my code example.