# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while Spring save data to MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

**This qustion is separated from**:
[Spring doesn't save object to MongoDB correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237986/spring-doesnt-save-object-to-mongodb-correctly)

I have `SampleClass` which has one field - `TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String,String>> map`. When I deploy application and run following code:

```
SampleClass sample = new SampleClass();
mongo.save(sample, "SampleCollection"); //MongoOperations object
```

I get following exception:

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0] with root cause
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.getComponentType(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:147)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.getActualType(TypeDiscoverer.java:292)
        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.getActualType(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:29)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.AbstractPersistentProperty.getPersistentEntityType(AbstractPersistentProperty.java:125)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:469)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:427)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:607)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:295)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:427)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:607)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:295)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:427)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:607)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:295)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:427)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:607)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:295)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:181)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:67)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getPersistentEntity(MongoTemplate.java:1831)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:829)
        at com.sample.MongoTest.saveToMongo(MongoTest.java:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This Exception is thrown only once after deployment. I figured out that when I replace field with `TreeMap<String, String>` it works fine, no exception can be observed.

Normally I would think that MongoDB has problems with handling map of maps( this case treeMap of treeMaps), but it's not.

The biggest problem is that it worked. My code is part of bigger module, which was migrated to separate project few days ago. When it was part of module it worked fine, but now when it's separated project it doesn't want to work.

**Questions time**

1. Is this possible to be configuration issue? It would be very weird if this is a problem. There is much more Mongo operations and everything works fine except saving/reading map of maps.
2. Some dependencies has been upgraded. What is the probability that this is the source of problems? ( it's hard for me to downgrade it and check if everything would work fine on older dependencies)
3. Does way of deployment may influence behavior of application?

I've tested this code with different Mongo backends and it behaves the same, so it's not problem with mongo instance.

---

**EDIT**

When I run application second time( after deployment when no Exception occurs) it saves data correctly. But because of Exception I cannot be sure if it would work fine on production.

Comment: did you look for Converters in the previous project? Maybe this class or The TreeMap was handled different

Comment: No, everything looks the same. At least my part of code. I've added more info

Comment: I can reproduce this error, looks like a bug inside of spring. You could raise an issue in their Jira bugtracker: https://jira.spring.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: This could be relevant too: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-887

Comment: this could be the result of a version mismatch. Please check your project dependencies for `spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE`. Handling of `TreeMap` has been fixed in `Codd SR2` and should be in the `Dijkstra` release as well.